# Debian 8 - Random freezing issues

Tags: debian, freeze

I've installed a dual boot Windows 10 / Debian 8 Jessie and frequently my laptop is totally freezing and I can't do anything about it : Everything is fixed including the mouse. I have to restart it manually.
The freezes happen randomly.

My environment is Gnome, my laptop is an Asus Zenbook UX32LN : Intel Core i5 4200U, 8go RAM, 256 GO SSD, and two graphical cards (Intel graphics and NVIDIA 840m)

I had Ubuntu and Elementary OS before Debian and it worked perfectly.

I don't know what other informations you need, just ask me !

Answer (score 1):

Do a:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-linux firmware-linux-free firmware-linux-nonfree intel-microcode
```

And reboot. That might fix the issue.

Comment: it says it can't find the package firmware-linux-nonfree and intel-microcode... But the first one has been installed. 
Do you know why I get those issues ?

Comment: I upgraded sources.list and I installed everything. I let you know if anything happens

Comment: there are still the same issues...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with mageia, zorin os (ubuntu) and manjaro (arch linux). Stopping time synchronisation solved it on manjaro:

```
sudo systemctl ntpd stop
```